# CodeIgniter CSRF working in IE not chrome or Firefox

Tags: php, codeigniter, csrf

I have done my best to troubleshoot this issue but have not been able to get this to work cross-browser.  Here is a link to the CodeIgniter document page http://goo.gl/YCKU7, scroll down to the bottom to see the section *Cross-site request forgery (CSRF)*.

Here are the steps I have ripped off a couple of forum posts.

1. Set config

   ```
   $config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;
   ```
2. remove '_' from cookie name

   ```
   $config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'sfe';
   $config['sess_expiration']      = 7200;
   $config['sess_expire_on_close'] = TRUE;
   $config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
   $config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
   $config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
   $config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
   $config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
   $config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;

   $config['csrf_protection']      = TRUE;
   $config['csrf_token_name']      = 'csrftestname';
   $config['csrf_cookie_name']     = 'csrfcookiename';
   $config['csrf_expire']          = 7200;
   ```
3. Cookie related variables

   ```
   $config['cookie_prefix']    = "";
   $config['cookie_domain']    = "";
   $config['cookie_path']      = "/";
   $config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;
   ```
4. create form with `form_open()`

Logs from `code_application/logs/`

```
DEBUG - 2013-04-04 18:33:10 --> Config Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2013-04-04 18:33:10 --> Hooks Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2013-04-04 18:33:10 --> Utf8 Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2013-04-04 18:33:10 --> UTF-8 Support Enabled
DEBUG - 2013-04-04 18:33:10 --> URI Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2013-04-04 18:33:10 --> Router Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2013-04-04 18:33:10 --> No URI present. Default controller set.
DEBUG - 2013-04-04 18:33:10 --> Output Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2013-04-04 18:33:10 --> Security Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2013-04-04 18:33:10 --> Input Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2013-04-04 18:33:10 --> XSS Filtering completed
DEBUG - 2013-04-04 18:33:10 --> XSS Filtering completed
DEBUG - 2013-04-04 18:33:10 --> XSS Filtering completed
DEBUG - 2013-04-04 18:33:10 --> CRSF cookie Set
DEBUG - 2013-04-04 18:33:10 --> Global POST and COOKIE data sanitized
DEBUG - 2013-04-04 18:33:10 --> Language Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2013-04-04 18:33:10 --> Loader Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2013-04-04 18:33:10 --> Helper loaded: form_helper
DEBUG - 2013-04-04 18:33:10 --> Helper loaded: url_helper
DEBUG - 2013-04-04 18:33:10 --> Database Driver Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2013-04-04 18:33:10 --> Form Validation Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2013-04-04 18:33:10 --> Session Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2013-04-04 18:33:10 --> Helper loaded: string_helper
DEBUG - 2013-04-04 18:33:10 --> A session cookie was not found.
DEBUG - 2013-04-04 18:33:13 --> Session routines successfully run
DEBUG - 2013-04-04 18:33:13 --> Controller Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2013-04-04 18:33:13 --> File loaded:     /home/rpowell/codeigniter/sfe/code_application/views/view_home.php
DEBUG - 2013-04-04 18:33:13 --> Final output sent to browser
DEBUG - 2013-04-04 18:33:13 --> Total execution time: 2.4202
DEBUG - 2013-04-04 19:25:32 --> Config Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2013-04-04 19:25:32 --> Hooks Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2013-04-04 19:25:32 --> Utf8 Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2013-04-04 19:25:32 --> UTF-8 Support Enabled
DEBUG - 2013-04-04 19:25:32 --> URI Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2013-04-04 19:25:32 --> Router Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2013-04-04 19:25:32 --> No URI present. Default controller set.
DEBUG - 2013-04-04 19:25:32 --> Output Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2013-04-04 19:25:32 --> Security Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2013-04-04 19:25:32 --> Input Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2013-04-04 19:25:32 --> XSS Filtering completed
DEBUG - 2013-04-04 19:25:32 --> XSS Filtering completed
DEBUG - 2013-04-04 19:25:32 --> XSS Filtering completed
DEBUG - 2013-04-04 19:25:32 --> XSS Filtering completed
DEBUG - 2013-04-04 19:25:32 --> XSS Filtering completed
DEBUG - 2013-04-04 19:25:32 --> CRSF cookie Set
DEBUG - 2013-04-04 19:25:32 --> Global POST and COOKIE data sanitized
DEBUG - 2013-04-04 19:25:32 --> Language Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2013-04-04 19:25:32 --> Loader Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2013-04-04 19:25:32 --> Helper loaded: form_helper
DEBUG - 2013-04-04 19:25:32 --> Helper loaded: url_helper
DEBUG - 2013-04-04 19:25:32 --> Database Driver Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2013-04-04 19:25:32 --> Form Validation Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2013-04-04 19:25:32 --> Session Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2013-04-04 19:25:32 --> Helper loaded: string_helper
DEBUG - 2013-04-04 19:25:32 --> Session routines successfully run
DEBUG - 2013-04-04 19:25:32 --> Controller Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2013-04-04 19:25:32 --> File loaded:     /home/rpowell/codeigniter/sfe/code_application/views/view_home.php
DEBUG - 2013-04-04 19:25:32 --> Final output sent to browser
DEBUG - 2013-04-04 19:25:32 --> Total execution time: 0.0520
```

I just stumbled upon this post: http://goo.gl/n63tC and will take a look if it has to do with my server's time.

Comment: As the post owner stated, after setting my csrf_expire parameter to anything over 7300 it would work in all browsers.  Recently I noticed that when I used current_timestamp as the default for some columns in my database that the time was off by an hour.  I host with hostgator and they had a great article to work around server time http://goo.gl/yIHlx.  I couldn't get the htcaccess fix to work but setting the default time zone to my timezone did the trick.`code`<?php 

// set site's default time zone
date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");?>`code`

Comment: Ok, everything was going great for the past three weeks and today out of the blue the error popped up again, any ideas?